# Angular Filters - filtering specific objects in an ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I have an ng-repeat that outputs different types of objects in an an array (text, date, datetime, currency).

Without using ng-repeat, I can add the filter directly to the specific object:

{{lastModifiedDate | date:'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm'}}

But if I use an ng-repeat, how do I apply filters to specific objects in the array?

---

EDIT:

Sorry - adding more information.

JSON:

```
[
    {
        "information": {
            "createdBy": "John Smith",
            "owner": "Jane Smith",
            "lastModifiedBy": "2017-04-13T17:14:17.000Z",
            "Future_Review_Date_Time__c": "2017-04-10T17:33:00.000Z",
            "CreatedDate": "2017-03-02T02:47:02.000Z",
            "Source": "Phone",
            "cost": "453"
        }
    }
]
```

If I did an ng-repeat over the json and want to add filters specifically for lastModifiedBy (Date), Future_Review_Date_Time__c (Date Time), CreatedDate (Date), and cost (Currency) - how do I add them?

Results:

- lastModifiedDate: MM-dd-yyyy
- Future_Review_Date_Time__c: MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm
- CreatedDate: MM-dd-yyyy
- cost: $

Comment: your question isn't clear.  why would you have an array with various primitives that you have to iterate through, rather than an object with the various properties?  `lastModifiedDate` isn't an object, it is a primitive in this example.  If you group the primitives as object properties, then you don't need to use `ng-repeat`, at least for a single group of properties....

Comment: @Claies sorry - just added more info!

Comment: so that's not an array, it's an object.  there is no reason to use `ng-repeat` here.  use `{{information.createdBy}}`, `{{information.lastModifiedDate : date:'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm'}}`, etc.  Why did you think you needed `ng-repeat`?

Comment: I just re-read my question and you're right, there's no reason to use ng-repeat here. I would normally just output it the way you have it. I guess, in a scenario that you're using an ng-repeat on an array and you want to add filters to a specific field, how does that work? thanks @Claies

Comment: it wouldn't work, and you would be recommended to re-format the array as an object.  Angular is data driven, and works best when you structure your data to match what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using as below

```
<div ng-repeat="item in someArray" >
    {{item.lastModifiedDate | date:'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm'}}

</div>
```

Comment: sorry I didnt get you

Comment: i guess they changed that ...my bad